# Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I faced this issue
    `Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version`
Then I followed this link http://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020.
It lead me to app crash at start up. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was the facebook login plug-in. When I commented it the app stopped crashing.

Comment: how should one have answered this question, without the `dependencies` from the `build.gradle`? this "solution" barely is the best possible answer to the problem.

Comment: the build gradle here was not the problem. It could have been if I had the facebook  activity there, but the only place I had it was inside the pubspecs.yaml